# Created a Next button for iOS app... giving SIGABRT error upon clicking

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a GoogleMaps based application. When the user is on MapViewController, I want them to be able to choose a location on the map and click Next at the Top right. Doing so should take them to another screen with a description of the location (HomeViewController). I'm stuck on implementing the Next button. My current code for the button looks like this...

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
....

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(MapViewController.next as (MapViewController) -> () -> ()))

}

     func next()
     {
        print("next")
        if let navController = self.navigationController, let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "indentfier") as? HomeViewController{
            navController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
     }
```

I ran it at first with just the `print("next")` and it worked (i.e., it just printed "next" to the console). When I added the second line with the push, the app started to crash when I clicked Next. I also got a SIGABRT error on my app delegate.

Note: HomeViewController is actually the home page; it's a previous screen that the user will have already seen a 4-5 screens before the map. I basically want them to go back a few screens to the home page  when they hit Next.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to tag your `next` function with `@objc`. Also `#selector(MapViewController.next as (MapViewController) -> () -> ())` this could just be `#selector(next)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.next(_:)))
```

---

```
@objc func next(_ bar:UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help... App delegate is still giving me a SIGABRT error, however. I changed my code as per your suggestion. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: may be there is a problem in your next vc **HomeViewController** create an empty controller and navigate to it to verify this also check if the next function is called or not , track your code with logs*breakpoints

Comment: Thanks Sh_Khan, I just needed to manually add a Segue from my MapVC to HomeVC.